# How can I fix "is a variable but is used like a type" error in my asp.net mvc Webapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to create the following Class on my `Main_Controller`, I get the error

> "CS0118 'prjname' is a variable but is used like a type"

Here is my code

```
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
        {
            var prjname = new prjname { Title = "Album " + id };
            return View(prjname);
        }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which class is prjname supposed to be? Try var prjname = new ClassName { Title = "Album " + id };

Comment: Look @Mostafiz answer. that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `prjname` is a anonymous type variable but you need to pass a specific model type in View, so create a model class for it and use same model type in View page

```
class SampleModel {
  public string Title {get;set;};
}

public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
{
      SampleModel  prjname = new SampleModel { Title = "Album " + id };
      return View(prjname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i had a Model called Aufgabe

Comment: so i edited like this:
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
        {
            var prjname = new Aufgabe { AufgTitel = "Aufgabe " + id };
            return View(prjname);
        }
and it worked :)

Comment: thats great, happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

The class name and variable name are the same, change it:

```
public ActionResult AufgabenDetails(int id)
        {
            var p= new prjname { Title = "Album " + id };
            return View(p);
        }
```